# using multiple hc-05 with one arduino mega

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, bluetooth, home-automation

please anyone help me build my project, i want to connect multiple smart phones to arduino mega using blutooth module hc-05 , I am working on real life home automation project and i don't have idea that can i use 4 Bluetooth modules with arduino mega . Requirement is max 4 smart phone connect to system , please anyone knowing about arduino please help ,i will be grateful . if u have any other suggestions tell me .

Comment: start with the example blink sketch ... try several of the example sketches that you can find in the Arduino IDE .... work your way up to bluetooth modules

Comment: do you know how to use one HC-05 module?

Comment: Yes i do , please help me to connect 4 Hc 05 in one Arduino mega, i need to connect 4 smartphones to one Arduino mega

Comment: I am making home automation project so it needs to connect 4 smartphones , looking forward for your help

Comment: This SE is for Q/A, not a project help service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HC-05 modules use Serial (UART) for communication with the Arduino. Thus you need 4 Serial interfaces for 4 HC-05 modules. The Arduino Mega has 4 hardware Serial interfaces, so just connect once HC-05 to each Serial interface. Then handle each module in your code the same just with a different Serial interface. If you already know, how to use one HC-05, then it should be rather easy to implement the same with all 4 modules.

Comment: can't one HC-05 communicate any number of smartphones (one at the time)?

Comment: Sure it can. But as I read the question the 4 smartphone should be connected at the same time